# How can I deploy template-based VM from Linux?

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, command-line-interface, vmware-vsphere

We are trying to provide our Linux engineers with a CLI to deploy VMWare vSphere VMs using templates.

The [vSphere CLI](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?productId=285&downloadGroup=VSP510-VCLI-510) looks promising but [the documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-51-command-line-interface-getting-started-guide.pdf) doesn't mention templates.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: Check out [ezmomi](https://github.com/snobear/ezmomi) which lets you clone templates to VMs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only option I've found would be using the [PySphere SDK](https://code.google.com/p/pysphere/)

I've used it to do snapshot consolidation and cleanup, but it can certainly do VM [creation from a template](https://dellaert.org/2013/03/04/pysphere-script-to-clone-a-template-into-multiple-vms-with-post-processing/).

Answer (score 2):

A couple of thoughts on this...

- It's almost easier to install Linux operating systems *anew* if you have a deployment solution and configuration management in place (e.g. Cobbler and Puppet/Chef). I tend not to use vSphere templates for anything other than canned Windows server installations.
- If that's not possible, and the template deployment process is infrequent, the standard vSphere Web Client and thick client are adequate.

The fact that you've phrased this as *"[providing] our Linux engineers with a CLI"*, makes me wonder if there's been some pushback, or reluctance to use the standard VMware tools.

Is there more context here?

Comment: Lack of VMWare Mac client seems to be the primary reason for the request. As is usually the case with Linux folks (myself included), there's a strong preference for CLI processes.

Comment: So this has changed over time. The last two releases of vSphere (5.1 and 5.5) have good Mac browser support. As someone who does this professionally, but is technically a Linux engineer by trade, I gravitate towards the right/appropriate tools for the job. For a *loooong* time, that meant keeping a Windows VM or RDP session around in order to use the vSphere client.

Answer (score 2):

There's a fling, [Ruby vSphere Console](https://labs.vmware.com/flings/rvc), that you can make use of.

If your Linux admins prefer Python they could use [pyVmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi), but it's more of a library (although you can start Python, import pyVmomi and then use it as a "shell").

There's also [virsh](http://libvirt.org/virshcmdref.html) but it looks like you can't deploy templates with it. However, googleing for virsh + deploy + template I found [vm-easy-deploy](https://github.com/amotoki/vm-easy-deploy) that might help you.