# vmware deployment from Linux or Ubuntu

Tags: linux, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx, ubuntu-14.04

Is there a way to deploy VMWare virtual machines from Linux? 
By deploy I mean provision from remote esx. 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do. What do you mean with "provision from remote esx"? Do you want to get a VM from an ESX and run it on Linux (KVM or Xen)? Or do you want to create a VM on an ESX from a Linux machine? Or do you want to deploy an OVF from a Linux machine to an ESX? Do you have a vCenter? What ESX / vCenter version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [virsh](http://libvirt.org/virshcmdref.html) can help you. Similar questions have been asked on serverfault before. Maybe the answers to them might help you, too. Two examples:

- [How can I deploy template-based VM from Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/618488/how-can-i-deploy-template-based-vm-from-linux)
- [Scripting VMWare ESXi from a linux server](https://serverfault.com/questions/640948/scripting-vmware-esxi-from-a-linux-server)

Comment: Close Enough Mario. Thank you greatly. The trick in finding the answer is usually in finding the right keywords. Thanks again, these links seems to point me in the right direction.